# eXist db index not used in xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

I have stored in my eXist db nodes of the following type:

```
<Order ID="170473" LnkID="8288374995" OrignDt="2003-07-08" TrdDt="2003-07-09" Acct="104158163" AcctIDSrc="99" DayBkngInst="ingrated" BkngUnit="hobbyhorse" SettlDt="2003-07-28" ClrFeeInd="B" HandlInst="3" MinQty="2088.58" ProcCode="1" Side="2"
LocReqd="N" TxnTm="2003-07-06T08:44:24" QtyTyp="0" Typ="A" PxTyp="4" Px="4258.33" Ccy="USD" SolFlag="N" IOIID="8596226323" ExpireDt="2003-06-19" GTBkngInst="2" Cpcty="A" Rstctions="A" CustCpcty="1660" ForexReq="Y" SettlCcy="inclination" Txt="eats" EncTxt="pendulous" Qty2="4028.86" MaxShow="1636.80" CxllationRights="M" MnyLaunderingStat="N" Designation="tied" >
<Hdr SID="997453497" D2ID="5969180787" SSub="swiftest" D2Sub="flay" PosDup="N" Snt="2003-10-24T12:13:50" OrigSnt="2003-07-19T00:23:46" MsgEncd="lechery" ><Hop ID="9148044310" Ref="33787" Snt="2003-08-24T21:26:11"></Hop>
</Hdr><Pty ID="8059449011" Src="H" ><Sub ID="228" ></Sub></Pty>
<Instrmt Sym="VRTS" Sfx="CD" ID="8962619773" Src="5" CFI="entrances" MatDt="2003-12-09" CpnPmt="2004-06-12" Issued="2004-05-14" RepoTrm="2749" CrdRtg="dad" IssuCtry="purpose" Redeem="2003-10-17" Strk="2028.23" StrkCcy="posterns" Exch="religiously" EncSecDescLen="4238" Pool="separation" IntAcrl="2003-08-17" ></Instrmt>
<OrdQty Qty="3652" Cash="3036.44" Pct="3882.34" RndDir="2" RndMod="1819.70" ></OrdQty>
</Order>
```

I would like to have an index for the ID attribute. My configuration file is:

```
   <collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<index>
    <create qname="@ID" type="xs:string"/>
</index>
<triggers>
    <trigger class="org.exist.extensions.exquery.restxq.impl.RestXqTrigger"/>
</triggers>
```

The index I have created is only used in pure xpath queries, such as

```
//Order[@ID ="170475"]
```

but not in xquery queries such as:

```
for $ord in//Order/@ID
where $ord = "150985"
return $ord
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change your query into

```xquery
for $ord in//Order
where $ord/@ID = "150985"
return $ord
```

The query engine tries to rewrite your expression in order to use the index. It will fail analyzing your previous formulation, but should succeed on the one above.

The general recommendation is to use XPath statements with filters where possible, because they are easier to rewrite automatically.

Comment: this makes sense, since the original query would not return $ord with usable data.

Answer (score 0):

It is [documented](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/tuning.xml#D2.2.6.6) that the eXist-db xquery processor has difficulties to optimize queries with the `where` clause.

Although your second query is syntactically correct, it is recommended to use the XPATH equivalent.